# "Edit Top 200 Rows" SQL Pane equivalent in SQL Server Data Tools "View Data"

Tags: visual-studio

I've always used *Edit Top 200 Rows* and then edited the query in the SQL pane of SQL Server 2008 Management Studio to find the rows I want to edit data for.

Now I have the tools inside Visual Studio 2012. I want to be able to change the query after right-clicking a table and choosing "View Data", but I can't see that this is possible.

Has the "SQL Pane" feature been removed or am I not seeing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. With SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), which is the new Visual Studio experience, there is no possibility to change the query, today.

This feature may return in the future. If you need it now, you have to use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

Comment: SSDT appear to have gone backwards with this. In Visual Studio I used to be able to "Show Data", pop open the SQL pane, run a query and then directly edit the results. Now MS in their infinite wisdom have pulled this feature when working on a 2012 SQL DB instance.

Answer (score 0):

To edit data in a table visually using the Data Editor (VS 2015 Data Tools):

Right-click the (yours) table in SQL Server Object Explorer, and select View Data (Show Table Data in VS 2010 Server Explorer).
...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272699(v=vs.103).aspx